# The famous epsilon-delta definition for finding the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

The objective is to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{x^3-4}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{4}{5}$.

For this, we start as follows:

Say for $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ and then prove that $|f(x)-\frac{4}{5}|<\epsilon$ where $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3-4}{x^2+1}$.

So, the objective becomes to find this $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ i.e $\delta (\epsilon)$ is required.

Now, the text I am reading does the following,

It lets $\delta=1$ initially and tries to get an upper bound on $\left|f(x)-\dfrac{4}{5}\right|$.

My doubt is, can we really do that ? Our objective is to find such a $\delta$ and we are starting of the proof with an arbitrary value of $\delta$ ? We could have taken $\delta=0.5,0.6,0.7$ or any other positive value and the solution would change accordingly, it's like we want to find a solution for a variable and we find that by assuming an arbitrary value of that variable initially, why ?

I mean something is wrong, may be my interpretation of the definition of the limit is wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: One can generally not take $\delta=1$, but one can always set an upper limit of $\delta$, e.g. $\delta \leq 1$.

Comment: You should probably include precisely what the text does and your trouble with it to get more accurate answers. At this point what I can say is think of your goal: it is to find one delta that works. How you find that delta is irrelevant, even if you started to randomly guess and were (extremely) lucky to actually find it, it doesn't matter, all that anyone cares is that good delta was found.

Comment: How do you decide whether the found delta is 'good' ? Is it that the smallest delta is the best ? How about when I take, say $\delta=0.8$ ? @Ennar

Comment: Actually my doubt is, why are we assuming the values of $\delta$ ? The problem is to find it, right ? How can we start assuming something that we eventually have to find ? @md2perpe

Comment: You decide that $\delta$ is "good" by verifying that the implication $0<|x-2|<\delta\implies |f(x)-4/5|<\epsilon$ is true. If it is, the delta is "good", otherwise it is not. The smallest "good" delta doesn't exist, actually, because if some $\delta_0$ is "good", then any $\delta\in(0,\delta_0)$ is "good" as well. Since $(0,\delta_0)$ doesn't have the smallest element, the smallest "good" delta doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, I get that. Now why do we assume a value of $\delta$ first ? We are supposed to find it and that too as a function of $\epsilon$, right ? @Ennar

Comment: I don't know, User9523, I haven't read your text :) As I said, if it will eventually lead to finding "good" delta, then why not. Have you heard of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)? It starts by guessing zero of a function, then uses that guess to find a better one, and then it continues to iterate it to infinity. Not quite the same as here, but just an example that taking some guess then building upon it to find something better is quite common.

Comment: What you need to understand is that you are *not* to find the *biggest* $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ when $|x-a|<\delta$. You just need to find *some* such $\delta$. If $\delta_0$ works, then also any $\delta<\delta_0$ works. Especially, no matter if $\delta_0$ is smaller or bigger than $1$, you can take it be smaller.

Comment: In my opinion, it might be useful to be a bit more specific about where this comes from than just mentioning *"the text I am reading"*. I guess this [counts as context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is easier to see in something like $\lim_{x \to 1} x^2=1$. You can write $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$. The second factor can be made small by making $\delta$ small. But the first factor can be large potentially. So you make the first factor not a problem by deciding in advance that $\delta$ is less than some constant. For instance if $|x-1|<1$ then $|x+1|<3$, so that $|x^2-1|<3|x-1|$. So $\delta=\min \{ \epsilon/3,1 \}$ works. Note that if you took $\epsilon=6$ then $\delta=\epsilon/3=2$ would fail: $|3^2-1|=8>6$. This is because of that $x+1$ factor getting too big. But $\delta=1$ still works, because $|2^2-1|=3<6$.

This is fine because you are just choosing any function $\delta(\epsilon)$ you want that has the property. It does not have to be as large as possible, nor does it need to be an increasing function. Geometrically this is because continuity at a point is a local property, in that only function values arbitrarily close to the point matter for it.

Comment: I don't know, it still seems confusing to me.
"You make the first factor not a problem by deciding in advance that $\delta $ less than some constant, taking $|x-1|<1$ => $|x|<3$ so that $|x+1|<3$ and hence $|x^2-1|<3|x-1|$..."
But isn't $|x-1|<1$ also ? Why are we ignoring that and are just setting $\delta=\epsilon/3$ ?

Comment: @User9523 We're not setting $\delta=\epsilon/3$ except when $\epsilon<3$. For $\epsilon>3$, $\delta=1$, and then $|x^2-1|<3|x-1|<3<\epsilon$. It is for such "big" $\epsilon$ values that the cutoff on $\delta$ kicks in.

Comment: @User9523 (Cont.) Note that we could alternately deal with it by deciding that $\epsilon \leq \epsilon_0$, computing an appropriate $\delta(\epsilon)$ on that range, and then setting $\delta(\epsilon)=\delta(\epsilon_0)$ for $\epsilon>\epsilon_0$. The strategy in my answer is saying "only small values of $\delta$ matter"; this strategy is saying "only small values of $\epsilon$ matter". Both are true.

Comment: One more thing, how are the cases $\delta<1$ and $\delta=1$ different ?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $|f(x) - 4/5| = \dfrac{|5x^3-4x^2-24|}{5(x^2+1)}= \dfrac{|x-2||5x^2+6x+12|}{5(x^2+1)}$. Next use $x^2+1 > 1$, $5x^2+6x+12 \le 5|x|^2+6|x|+12< 5\cdot 3^2+6\cdot 3+12 = 75$. This comes from $|x| \le |x-2|+2 < 1+2 = 3$ for $|x-2| < \delta = 1$ as you chose earlier. Can you put these together to make a proof? You choose $\delta = 1$ for convenience, and you can choose any positive delta small enough to make $|f(x) - 4/5| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I get that, my doubt was, why assume a value of something you have to find ?

Comment: The problem boils down to find the delta in terms of the epsilon. Delta is usually very small between $0$ and $1$.